# Remote AJAX call when checking a ceckbox in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, checkbox

If I have a checkbox in Rails3, How can I perform a remote AJAX call when the user changes the value of it.

It sound like a simple task, but I fail to find a good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of check-box on change event to the form and by using :remote => true you can use AJAX in form_for.syntax of on changing the check box and submitting the form is            **":onchange => "this.form.submit()**
I hope this would help you.
Thanks.